# How to display span content in one line inside li tag?

Tags: html, css

I have to display span tag content  in one line inside li tag. Would you help me in this?

I am getting output like this.
[image]

I need output like this.
[image]

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

ul li h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide `display: inline-block` to your `li`, `h2` and `span`.

Give your span appropriate `width` so that it gets accommodated within the space between both the `li`.

To view in full screen, check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/s4tqwcmr/

Refer code:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}

ul li h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.nashceez, In case If I have to add the button then how can I add it inside li tag. that will display beside span

Comment: You have to apply `position: absolute` on the `button` and position it accordingly inside the `li` tag.

Comment: Thanks for replying Again Mr.nashceez. Working for me. Upvote from my side..and sorry for late reply

Comment: Mr.nashcheez, I have small content in first li and large content in the second li, but it is not displaying in one line

Comment: Provide `vertical-align: top` to both the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Add inline-block to your li this will let them have a specific width and not acting like an inline element...

```css
ul
{
  list-style: none;
}
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul li h2{
  display: inline-block;
  width:40%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul li span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:39%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul li button{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19%;
  min-width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem     </span>
    <button>button</button>
 </li>
  <li>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem     </span>
    <button>button</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.RenzoCC, In case If I have to add on button then how can I add it inside li tag

Comment: Not sure If I understood correctly but assuming you want to add an inline button you can decrease the span and the h2 width, in order to fit with the new button just like in the snippet...

Comment: Right, Mr.Renzocc, My issue got resolved before. Your solution is also working. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul
{
 list-style: none;
}

ul li{
        width: 40%;
        display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
ul li h2{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
 <li>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem </span>
 </li>

  <li>
   <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```